# Getting template not found error in django

Tags: python, django

I have tried everything thing and path is correct in view.py but getting template doesn't found error in django
My views.py

```py
def starting_page(request):
    return render(request,"tractor/index.html")

def posts(request):
    return render(request,"tractor/all-post.html")
```

I have also added ss of error and my directory.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please share your screenshot of the project structure (Generally it is located on the left side of IDE and shows placement of files and folders) and `settings.py` file.

Comment: @black please see the screenshots it is present there.

Comment: They don't have `settings.py` file. Also they don't include how your html template files are located within `templates` folder.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [ask]. **Don't** upload images of code / errors as mentioned in the linked "How to Ask" page (Even for the directory structure don't do that, paste that in as text as a filetree). Getting to your question the problem likely is: you haven't added your app to `INSTALLED_APPS`...

Answer (score 1):

We can try to follow the structure as set in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-an-app-s-template-directory), so try moving your files to the following locations within your app (assuming `my_proj` is the name of your django project and `tractor` is the name of the app):

```
my_proj/tractor/templates/tractor/index.html
my_proj/tractor/templates/tractor/all-post.html
```

To ensure those html files would be found, verify if your `settings.py` is correctly configured with this as documented.

> First, make sure your template settings are checking inside app directories:
>
> ```py
> TEMPLATES = [
>     {
>         ...,
>         'APP_DIRS': True,
>         ...
>     },
> ]
> ```

Or if your files are in the project and not in the app:

> ```py
> TEMPLATES = [
>     {
>         ...
>         'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
>         ...
>     },
> ]
> ```

Comment: Yes I have correct setting and directory is also right you can check the screenshots I have sent but then also it's not working .

Comment: @Max_len I updated my answer. Could you try adding `'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],` in the `TEMPLATES` in `settings.py`